# Replacing NaN Values in a Pandas DataFrame with Different Random Uniform Variables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, statistics, data-science

I have a uniform distribution in a pandas dataframe column with a few NaN values I'd like to replace.

Since the data is uniformly distributed, I decided that I would like to fill the null values with random uniform samples drawn from a range of the column's min and max values. I used the following code to get the random uniform sample:

```
df_copy['ep'] = df_copy['ep'].fillna(value=np.random.uniform(3, 331))
```

Of course, using `pd.DafaFrame.fillna()` replaces all existing NaNs with the same value. I would like each NaN to be a different value. I assume that a `for` loop could get the job done, but am unsure how to create such a loop to specifically handle these NaN values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please look up df.where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looks like you are doing this on a series (column), but the same implementation would work on a DataFrame:

Sample Data:

```
series = pd.Series(range(100))

series.loc[2] = np.nan
series.loc[10:15] = np.nan
```

Solution:

```
series.mask(series.isnull(), np.random.uniform(3, 331, size=series.shape))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df_copy['ep'].isna()

df_copy.loc[m, 'ep'] = np.random.uniform(3, 331, size=m.sum())
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!